# Highcharts mixed column/spline, wrong xaxis labels

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to finalize a graph where I report the daily production within a month and a couple of other daily based series. The graph is always set at full scale, meaning that I always show all the days within a month, even if I do not have values for them, whichever is the reason why. On the first day of each month, I display the graph of the previous month, as a report.

[This is the jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/5yqv0uah/) I've set up so that you can have an idea. The problem I've been fighting against is that, whatever I try to do, Highcharts simply ignores me and displays wrong labels on x axis. So the days start from 2, go throughout the whole month to the last and they end with 1.

This is the code for my chart:

```
$(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'tab-month-graph',
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Daily - August 2015'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    text: 'Giorni',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '10px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                },
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%e'
                }
            },
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'Produzione giornaliera',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                    }
                }
            },
            { // Secondary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'PR giornaliero',
                    style: {
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                    }
                },
                min: 0,
                startOnTick: false,
                opposite: true
            }],
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                 name: 'Prod.',
                 type: 'column',
                 data: [[1438466230000, 4603.36],[1438552630000, 4264.92],[1438639030000, 3108.05],[1438725430000, 2047.03],[1438811830000, 2270.39],[1438898230000, 2258.2],[1438984630000, 3971.95],[1439071030000, 3784.45],[1439157430000, 3674.53],[1439243830000, 3131.95],[1439330230000, 1963.13],[1439416630000, 3333.52],[1439503030000, 4161.8],[1439589430000, 4408.59],[1439675830000, 2968.83],[1439762230000, 2808.05],[1439848630000, 4439.77],[1439935020000, 3746.48],[1440021430000, 4980],[1440107830000, 3683.91],[1440194230000, 4480.78],[1440280630000, 4406.48],[1440367030000, 4518.98],[1440453430000, 4492.73],[1440539830000, 3924.14],[1440626230000, 4062.89],[1440712630000, 3225.47],[1440799030000, 3213.75],[1440885430000, 4631.95],[1440971830000, 4471.17],[1441058230000, 4223.91]],
                 color: '#89CE7F',
                 dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        rotation: -90,
                        color: '#000000',
                        align: 'right',
                        x: 4,
                        y: 10,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '11px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                            }
                        }
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'PR',
                    type: 'spline',
                    yAxis: 1,
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    marker: {
                        radius: 6
                    },
                    data: [[1438466230000, 73.36],[1438552630000, 75.08],[1438639030000, 57.54],[1438725430000, 38.85],[1438811830000, 39.14],[1438898230000, 63.78],[1438984630000, 76.03],[1439071030000, 75.78],[1439157430000, 77.61],[1439243830000, 79.74],[1439330230000, 77.35],[1439416630000, 73.98],[1439503030000, 75.79]],
                    color: '#AA0000',
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' %'
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'PR Cont.',
                    type: 'spline',
                    yAxis: 1,
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                        symbol: 'circle'
                    },
                    data: [[1438466230000, 78.84],[1438552630000, 79.85],[1438639030000, 75.16],[1438725430000, 59.15],[1440971830000, 78.5],[1441058230000, 78.45]],
                    color: '#BBBB00',
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ' %'
                    }
                } 
                ],
            tooltip: {
                xDateFormat: '%A, %d %B %Y',
                valueSuffix: ' kW',
                shared: true    //  LEGENDA CONDIVISA
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 7, 1),
                    pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I've read tons of posts on Stack Overflow, tried tons of suggestions, I've even tried [this post tinyurl.com/psbzxeh on HighCharts official forum](https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/xaxis-type-datetime-giving-wrong-labels-t19135/) which is referred to a similar problem, but it did not solve my issue.
Could someone point me out to the right solution?

Comment: If I try startOnTick: true in the xAxis settings, the xAxis labels start from 1 go up to 31 and end with one, while the columns always start from 2. So it seems that something is wrong with the data I am passing to the chart? :'( even more frustrating than before.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify things: columns look like translated by one day, because of that time (`21:57:10 UTC`) - which is almost another day (without UTC it's 23:57:10 for GMT+2:00). In general, if you have daily data, then it's better to use `00:00:00` as this is when exactly date starts. Manipulating JSON shouldn't be that hard, see:

```
function modify(data) {
    var time;
    data.map(function(e) {
        time = new Date(e[0]);
        time.setUTCHours(0);
        time.setUTCMinutes(0);
        time.setUTCSeconds(0);

        e[0] = time.getTime();
        return e; 
    });
    return data;
}
```

And:

```
   series: [{
        name: 'Prod.',
        type: 'column',
        data: modify([
            [1438466230000, 4603.36],
            ...
        ])
   }]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p7vnqmt7/3/

Note: to remove extra tick at the last place on the axis, you can simply set `xAxis.max`.

And to answer question in the comment: no, `pointInterval` shouldn't be used when you have data as x-y pair.

Comment: Your solution is great, but I have some doubts and I am a bit concerned about dates. First of all, if I apply the transformation of the ts to all the series, I see that there is no need to use te xAxis.max (at least I've tried to do so with your code and it works). Now, what is the best solution in order to avoid problems with data (displaying the graph in different fuses): rewrite my php code so that timestamps are passed to highcharts at 0:00:00 of each day, and tell highCharts not to use UTC, or pass timestamp as they are in the database and then manipulate them with your "modify" function?

Comment: Considering that I am writing my code so that it can be properly displayed on mobile devices (even smartphones), the above question has to be read having fluidity on such devices. Thanks

Comment: It's up to you - I would modify dates in JS, because you may need the same dates in other places with exact time. From the other hand, that logic should be placed in back-end, so view/front will only display information, not modify them, I think. Mobile devices doesn't change anything in your case, or did I miss something?

Comment: No, i am Just concerned with fluency. In other words, i would like to make the graph as light as possibile in order to move the load on the server, so that the chart gets loaded and displayed quickly. Modifying up to 93 timestamps on a mobile device could bring in a bit overhead, don't you think? I think i will go for the back-end solution. Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: Just a note: Modifying ~100 items in array won't slow down your app :) JS is quite fast, DOM operations are not.

Comment: Thanks Pawel Fus for your precious snippet (modify function) and for your help. I finally decided to modify the php script that generates the arrays, so that the timestamps are set at the proper date/time. Now highcharts is displaying everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

try below function above your highchart function and set xAxis min and max.
Use very first timestamp(date) as min and last timestamp(date) as max value.

```
    $( function () {
                            Highcharts.setOptions( {
                                lang : {
                                    rangeSelectorZoom : ' '
                                },
                                global : {
                                    useUTC : false
                                }
                            } );
                        } );
```

Comment: I've just tried your suggestion, but no success :( I had already tried the useUTC:false solution without success. The odd thing is that highCharts seems to disregard anything I try to change the start of xAxis values. For example, shouldn't pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 7, 1) force highcharts to start from the 1st of August?

Comment: I viewed your data again .The very first data-point starts at "1438466230000" which is having values as                                             GMT: Sat, 01 Aug 2015 21:57:10 GMT
Your time zone: 8/2/2015, 3:27:10 AM GMT+5:30   So it seems to be started at 21:57 on saturaday 1 Aug but in my timezone its starting on 2 Aug. This could be the reason its showing wrong label on your axis. Plz recheck are you using useUtc: false at proper place.

Comment: I will update the jsFiddle with your code in the right place, at least I hope it is so... ok, done. It seems that nothing changed :'( For my timezone, the timestamp you pointed out should be Aug 1st 2015 23.57

Comment: I've just tried to use 1438387200000 as timestamp for the first value, and the 1 on the xAxis is there! So it is just a matter of "datetime". At least we have found a way to handle this issue... now I need a solution. Manipulating all the timestamp it is not a good idea, since it would complicate a bit the code that generates the jSon arrays passed to the charts.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the right direction! It was just a matter of timestamps.